# "Targeted" deep watch in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Suppose I have an array of objects like this:

```
$scope.data = [
  {
    "active": true,
    "id": "4bcb19db-ec10-4de5-8ae6-b13388494651",
    "name": "Owais Shah",
    "username": "chekhov"
  },
  {
    "active": false,
    "id": "630d0582-1bf9-4331-9fa6-f6baa59319b2",
    "name": "Tim Hunt",
    "username": "one"
  }
]
```

I can use this to deep watch the object:

```
$scope.$watch('data', function(){...}, true)
```

However, this is not efficient in my case, as the only property of these objects that I'm interest in watching is `active`.

Is there a way to watch only a specific property deep inside the object? Something like `$scope.$watch('data[].active' ...)`

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to watch only certain parameter inside objects in an array. You either watch the reference or a value of the variable

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do something like this:

```
for(var i=0,j=$scope.data.length;i<j;i++) {
   $scope.$watch(data[i].active, function() {   });

}
```

Comment: and if there were million elements in an array... yaaaaay a million watches to slow down the application

Comment: What is there are only 10?  If there are a million I'd question why they need to watch all of them, but that is NOT my determination to make.

Answer (score 1):

You can watch on a function which in turn returns your inner objects

```
$scope.$watch(    function() { 
                     return $scope.data.active[0]; 
                  }, 
                  function(newValue, oldValue) { 
                     console.log('It changed!'); 
                  }
              );
```

Comment: will $scope.data.active really return anything in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the $watch function accepting a function and return a value you compute from the array. For example, you could look at it is a number based on the binary sequence of 0/1 for active = false or true. Something like this would work:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
        var value = 0, idx;
        for (idx = 0; idx < $scope.data.length; idx += 1) {
            value *= 2;
            value += $scope.data[idx].active ? 1 : 0;
        };
        return value;
    }, function() { 
        $scope.changes += 1;
        $scope.status = "Changed " + $scope.changes + " times."; });
```

The jsFiddle here illustrates it: http://jsfiddle.net/jeremylikness/GrRtK/

You can see it illustrated by clicking the same button. The first time the element changes from true to false or vice versa, the change is registered, while subsequent updates do not trigger the watch. It will be even more readable if you use a mapping function from underscore to project the array onto your number or value to watch.